# include Facebook Pixel Code js in orchard

Tags: orchardcms

I need to add Facebook Pixel Code script in head section of every page.

```
<!-- Facebook Pixel Code -->
<script>
!function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s){if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;
n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window,
document,'script','//connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');

fbq('init', 'xxx');
fbq('track', "PageView");</script>
<noscript><img height="1" width="1" style="display:none"
src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=xxx&ev=PageView&noscript=1"
/></noscript>
<!-- End Facebook Pixel Code -->
```

How can get this?
I recently started working on orchard. I read about edit cshtml or edit the theme...

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be a **Layout.cshtml** file in your themes directory, where you can add the script like this:

```
@using ( Script.Head() )
{
    <!-- Facebook Pixel Code -->
    <script>
        !function (f, b, e, v, n, t, s) {
            if (f.fbq) return; n = f.fbq = function () {
                n.callMethod ?
                n.callMethod.apply(n, arguments) : n.queue.push(arguments)
            }; if (!f._fbq) f._fbq = n;
            n.push = n; n.loaded = !0; n.version = '2.0'; n.queue = []; t = b.createElement(e); t.async = !0;
            t.src = v; s = b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(t, s)
        }(window,
        document, 'script', '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');

        fbq('init', 'xxx');
        fbq('track', "PageView");</script>
        <noscript>
            <img height="1" width="1" style="display:none"
                 src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=xxx&ev=PageView&noscript=1" />
        </noscript>
    <!-- End Facebook Pixel Code -->
}
```

Alternatively, you could copy the **Document.cshtml** located in *Orchard.Web\Core\Shapes\Views* into your theme and insert the script directly in the head section.

Comment: What is best practice between two solutions??

Comment: I prefer to have my global scripts in the Document.cshtml and use the first approach whenever I need to load a specific script from other shapes. But it's completely up to you, I don't think there's really a best practice to it.
I just like to have the scripts where they belong.